# PostGIS ST_Scale with factor and origin

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to buffer points and scale the buffer around the points themselves. According to the [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Scale.html) this can be done by supplying the factor as a point to the second argument and the origin to the third.

But my scaled buffers are not coming out correctly and have no extent according to QGIS. How can I scale the buffers around the points' origins?

Here's an example of what I have currently:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS zones;
CREATE TABLE zones AS (
WITH
coords AS (
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
    (1, 101, 201),
    (2, 104, 204),
    (3, 109, 209)
   ) p(id, x, y)
),
points AS (
    SELECT id, st_setsrid(st_point(x, y), 32616) geom
      FROM coords
)
SELECT id, ST_Scale(st_buffer(geom, 1), ST_Point(4, 8), geom) geom
  FROM points
)
```

Comment: Have you tried just specifying the size of the buffer in the second argument of [ST_Buffer](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html)?

Comment: How are your points not coming out correctly? The scaled points have an area of 99.86, and most definitely have an extent. If you put an ST_Area or ST_AsText around ST_Scale you will see this.

Comment: Are you trying to scale in place, if so, you probably want the centroid of the geometry as the last parameter.